# Scrolling content within nested flexbox columns (with dynamic heights)

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a page with a global header and footer (with dynamic heights), and a card in the center of the remaining area of the page that shrinks or grows depending on the content within the card.

The card itself also has a header and footer that I need to stay visible on the page while the content in the center is the portion that scrolls. I am having the hardest time trying to figure out how to get this done.

Edit: I know I can accomplish this by giving the card-content a max-height but since all the heights of the global and card header and footers are dynamic, I have no idea what max height to give at any given time? Or would I need a javascript solution to accomplish this?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Yorria/pen/yWaWxg

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Model:

[image: Model]

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.global-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-wrapper {
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.card-wrapper-inner {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.card-content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* ignore: forcing overflow */

.overflow-content {
  height: 2000px;
}

.global-info {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="global-container">
  <div class="global-info">Global Header</div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card-wrapper-inner">
      <div class="card">
        <div>Card Header</div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="overflow-content">
            I want only this content to scroll, and to shrink if it doesn't take up the entire page.
            <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut nec dapibus libero. Cras sollicitudin consectetur nunc, ac faucibus tellus feugiat vel. Morbi sollicitudin, ex eu consectetur pulvinar, nibh elit ullamcorper erat, eu viverra
            sem dui eu orci. Mauris auctor dapibus lectus ac iaculis. Vivamus varius enim non dui porttitor condimentum. Pellentesque euismod massa id imperdiet tincidunt. Mauris imperdiet leo in enim malesuada lacinia. Sed eget porta ligula, nec mollis
            quam. Nullam viverra ex lorem, eget euismod ligula gravida vel. Vestibulum accumsan lacinia consectetur.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>Card Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="global-info">Global Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help the browser pass along full heights to descendant containers. They're having trouble getting past `.card-wrapper-inner`.

Just add `display: flex` to that class. That command activates the `align-items: stretch` default, which consumes all available height from the parent, and makes it available to the child.

Put another way, there was a missing link in the chain. Full heights weren't able to get past a level. By making `.card-wrapper-inner` a flex container, the height rules get passed down from top to bottom.

[revised codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QRGLaj)

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.global-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-wrapper {
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.card-wrapper-inner {
  display: flex;  /* new */
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}

.card-content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* ignore: forcing overflow */

.overflow-content {
  height: 2000px;
}

.global-info {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="global-container">
  <div class="global-info">Global Header</div>
  <div class="card-wrapper">
    <div class="card-wrapper-inner">
      <div class="card">
        <div>Card Header</div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <div class="overflow-content">
            I want only this content to scroll, and to shrink if it doesn't take up the entire page.
            <br/>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut nec dapibus libero. Cras sollicitudin consectetur nunc, ac faucibus tellus feugiat vel. Morbi sollicitudin, ex eu consectetur pulvinar, nibh elit ullamcorper erat, eu viverra
            sem dui eu orci. Mauris auctor dapibus lectus ac iaculis. Vivamus varius enim non dui porttitor condimentum. Pellentesque euismod massa id imperdiet tincidunt. Mauris imperdiet leo in enim malesuada lacinia. Sed eget porta ligula, nec mollis
            quam. Nullam viverra ex lorem, eget euismod ligula gravida vel. Vestibulum accumsan lacinia consectetur.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>Card Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="global-info">Global Footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a max height to the card div and set the card-content to scroll

Pen example here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xNEoVQ

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.global-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-wrapper {
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.card-wrapper-inner {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 70%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 70vh;
}

.card-content {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #ddd;
  overflow: scroll;
  height:50vh;
}

/* ignore: the overflow content itself */
.overflow-content {
  height: 2000px;
}

.global-info {
  background-color: green;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: my max-height is dynamic though depending on the global and card header and footer heights (they actively change), is there no way to have it scroll without giving it a max height?